# Showing error while installing laravel

Tags: php, laravel

have got this error while installing Laravel

```
PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/Laravel/laraout/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/Laravel/laraout/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/Laravel/laraout/artisan:0
PHP   2. require() /var/www/html/Laravel/laraout/artisan:16
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/Laravel/laraout/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/Laravel/laraout/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/Laravel/laraout/artisan:0
PHP   2. require() /var/www/html/Laravel/laraout/artisan:16
```

I have tried this source solve this

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel laraout "5.2.*" --no-scripts
```

But it is not working for me.

Comment: `working for me` or not ??

Comment: Sorry i have edited this

Comment: I have tried the chmod also for the permission.

Comment: Did you run `composer install` ?

Comment: Yes, I have done that also.

Comment: What's your php version?

Comment: What is your method of installing laravel? Do you have laravel installed globally? Project basis? Which OS are you using? Which composer version do you have? PHP version?

Comment: I am using Linux mint, Composer Ver 1.5.5, PHP 7.1.12 and i have installed it by this command "composer create-project laravel/laravel laraout"

Comment: I've just installed a new laravel project using the command that you posted. 

Comment: This is very unfortunate

Comment: I am using Linux mint. PHP 7, Nodejs v9.2.0 and NPM  5.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "" try this

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel laraout 5.2.*
```

just copy past the above command

Comment: Have the same problem.

Comment: I don't know it may help please use this " php composer.phar require aws/aws-sdk-php " in command promp i get this from https://github.com/ACloudGuru/dynamodb/issues/3

Comment: which server are you using?

Comment: Apache2 server in my localhost

Answer (score -1):

Please Run `composer install` or `composer update` if you have already run `composer install` from your terminal inside your project.